# explanation of the souce code of strcat()

Tags: c, c-strings, sizeof, strlen, strcat

```
    char *
STRCAT(char *dest, const char *src)
{
  strcpy(dest + strlen(dest), src);
  return dest;
}
```

what's the meaning of the code :dest + strlen(dest)?
and when I use the code like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    char s[10]= "123456789";
    char str[10] = " 123456789";
    strcat(s,str);
    printf("%s\n",s);
    printf("%d",sizeof(s));
    
}
```

why the string s didn't overflow  and the sizeof(s) did not change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcat` and `STRCAT` are two different functions.:)

I think you mean the function name `strcat` instead of `STRCAT` in this declaration

```
    char *
strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
  strcpy(dest + strlen(dest), src);
  return dest;
}
```

This function is designed to deal with strings that is with sequences of characters terminated by the zero character `'\0'`.

The function `strlen` returns the number of characters in a string before the terminating zero character `'\0';`.

So the expression  `dest + strlen(dest)` points to the terminating zero character `'\0'` of the string contained in the destination character array. Thus the function `strcat` can append the source string to the string stored in the destination array starting from the terminating zero.

So for example if you have a character array declared like

```
char dest[3] = { '1', '0' };
```

and the source array declared like

```
char src[2] = { '2', '0' };
```

For the array `dest` the function `strlen( dest )` will return the value `1`.

As a result `dest + strlen( dest )`  points to the second character of the array `dest` that is the zero character `'0'`. And this call

```
strcpy(dest + strlen(dest), src);
```

will copy characters of the string stored in the array `src` in the array `dest` starting with this position and you will get the following content of the array dest

```
{ '1', '2', '\0' }
```

In your program the expression `sizeof( s )` gives the number of elements with which the array s is declared

```
char s[10]= "123456789"
```

that is `10`. This value specified in the declaration of the array does not depend on the content that the array will have and is calculated at the compile time.

Pay attention to that values returned by the operator `sizeof` have the type `size_t`. So to output them using the function `printf` you have to use the conversion specifier `zu`. For example

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(s));
```

In your program the array `str`

```
char str[10] = " 123456789";
```

does not contain a string because it does not have a space to accommodate the (eleventh ) terminating zero character of the string literal used as an initializer.

On the other hand, the array s does not have a space to be able to append another string to its tail.

So your program has undefined behavior.

A valid program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = " 123456789";
    char s[10 + sizeof( str ) - 1] = "123456789";

    strcat( s, str );

    printf( "%s\n", s);

    printf( "%zu\n", strlen( s ) );

    printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( s ) );
}
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Thanks for so detailed answer.I don't know the specifier zn before.I will follow these standards.

Answer (score 3):

> what's the meaning of the code :dest + strlen(dest)

It calculates the pointer to the end of the `dest` because with `strcat` you want to append the second string to the end of the first. It similar to:

```
size_t l = strlen(dest);
char *p = &dest[l];  // dest + l pointer arithmetic.
strcpy(p, src);
```

> why the string s didn't overflow and the sizeof(s) did not change?

`s` is overflowing, because after `strcat` is done, your string is now 20 characters long, while it holds only room for 10 characters. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

`sizeof` doesn't change, because it is determined at compile time, so it will always show the same value.

Comment: Due to the security implications, it is highly recommended to use `strncat` as a safer implementation instead of `strcat`.